# How to expand an image in HTML by clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image in my html page.

```
<img src="http://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/sMONYSiLUQEvooJ5hZh0Sw/l.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="150">
```

How can I show it enlarged in the same page by clicking on it?.

Comment: Do you know JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, but im not an expert. I just started with HTML and javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this will help you

```
<img src="http://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/sMONYSiLUQEvooJ5hZh0Sw/l.jpg" class="img" alt="" width="200" height="150">


.img:hover{
    color: #424242; 
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.15);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.15); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15); /* Safari and Chrome */

}
```

You can transform Scale as per your requirement.

Comment: This is hovering not clicking

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with pure css3 `transform: scale();`

Show [EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/AXaBaya/2/edit)

Answer (score 6):

Ideally the `<img>` would have an `id` or class (especially if there are multiple of them).  The simplest way would probably be to add a class although you could also change the width property or style property.

```
/* CSS */
.enlarged {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}

// JavaScript
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelector("img"), function (elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("click", function () {
        elem.classList.toggle("enlarged");
    });
});
```

You will require at least IE10 for some of the above like [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList) unless you define the methods yourself like the documentation has

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery's Click() and Attr() functions

HTML:
Add an ID such as thumbnailImage.

jQuery:

```
$("#thumbnailImage").click(function() {
   $(this).attr('width', '400');
    $(this).attr('height', '300');
});
```

See my jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/VyYkE/1/

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following using jQuery.

```
$(function ()
{
    $('img').on('click', function ()
    {
        $(this).width(1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

give image an id

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#imageid').on('click', function ()
    {
        $(this).width(1000);
    });
});
```