# WP Metaslider onclick enlarge image same screen

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, onclick, slideshow

so I'm using WP metaslider for a slideshow/gallery display.  Everything works great with it, except instead of clicking on the image in the slider and opening its original size in a new window, I would prefer to click on the image in the slider and it enlarging within the slide, similar to the accordion gallery styles, but I want the image clicked on to get larger and the other images to remain the same size or get smaller.

I've tried CSS and javascript shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104018/how-to-expand-an-image-in-html-by-clicking-on-it?answertab=active#tab-top) but it did not work.

I am open to other plugins that may give me a closer result than this, but the accordion plugin [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/accordion-slider-lite/)  is the next closet but I still want to be able to see all of the images without them being cut off.

http://kerimthedj.com/new/photos

Comment: I kind of need you to clarify. Would you rather like a preview of the image in it's original size? Or just enlarge it within the slider?

Also, the JS you've linked to makes use of the jQuery library. Make sure you've referenced to the jQuery file in your HTML `<head>` tag.

Comment: I referenced the jquery library in the header tag, I don't believe it worked with the plugin however.  --I would like to enlarge the image within the slider itself.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this today. Even though some years have passed, I had the same doubt today. So here is how it is done: https://www.metaslider.com/docs/how-do-i-open-an-image-in-a-lightbox-modal

You basically have to:

1. Install the `MetaSlider` plugin
2. Install two more plugins: `MetaSlider Lightbox` and a "lightbox plugin" (in my case: `Easy FancyBox`).
3. Create a slide (or use the one you have), at the right panel at "Advanced" please select "Open in lightbox". You can edit settings at the small "Edit settings" link.
4. Click `save` then test on your published page.