# How to display enlarged images upon click in a new pop up window similar to Twitter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

An image on Twitter, will enlarge in a pop up window which can be closed using the `x`. I have seen similar questions such as [How to expand an image in HTML by clicking on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104018/how-to-expand-an-image-in-html-by-clicking-on-it) but I want the image to open, enlarged, in a separate window rather than being enlarged on the page.

At the moment, I realize `<a></a>` tags are commonly used to achieve enlarged images, but a pop up window seems more aesthetically pleasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a link with the `<a></a>` tag and set the target to something like "_blank" it will force the image to pop up in its own window.

```
 <a href="url" target = "_blank"> <img src="url"/></a>
```

The inner `<img/>` tag will display the image from the url (which can be a local directory in your project such as "/images/test.jpg" or an external source).  The `<a></a>` tag surrounding it will make the image clickable and open the href in a new window because the target is set as above.